# My JS is adding a space when converting ascii to string

Tags: javascript, function, ascii

i have a function here takes input parameter. it then iterates and changes the values from Ascii to strings

im using node.js and testing files and for some reason my code is adding a space to the result. any help please?

```
function stringify(input) {

var result = "";

for (var i=0; i<=input.length; i++) {
    result+=String.fromCharCode(input[i]);
}

return result;

}
```

Comment: The problem seems not to be related to the piece of code you pasted. Try to narrow it down and post the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

You condition should check till `length-1` and not till `length` of the string `input`

```
function stringify(input) {

var result = "";

for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++)//< instead of <=
{
    result+=String.fromCharCode(input[i]);
}

return result;

}
```

You have to only go till `length-1` as the last character of the string is the [`null` character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) which is a [whitespace character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). When you copy it to the `result` variable it comes as space along with the rest of the string.